# Parse a Comma Delimited File using JAVA

Tags: java

I want to read this file:-

```
http://www.somehost.com/products/, A0,D1,L0,T0
http://www.somehost.com/news/rel, A1,D0,L1,T0
http://istor.somehost.com, A0, D1, L0, T0
```

I have a list of urls and I want to compare those url's with the url's that are there in this file. And Suppose the url that I wanted to compare starts with the url that is there in these file.. Then it will move forward in that url line and it will check for A and D. If A is 0 then we will not crawl that url and vice versa and If A is 1 then we will move forward and see  whether L is 0 or 1 means if L is 1 then we will extract link only and vice versa and same with T is 0 or 1, we will extract text only if T is 0.

Any suggestion how can I do this.. ??

Comment: I think this is where you employ the technique known as "programming".  You can, of course, use String.split to do some of the work.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks,Yeah I know that... I just wanted to know the logic.. What logic we should use here...!!

Comment: What do you mean by "logic"?  Read line, parse line, interpret parsed data.

Comment: @Daniel - sounds like someone wants everythin done for them.

Comment: IMHO, If your data is simple as you show it above, then the solution is trivial and you have no need for our suggestions. If the data is complex and for instance contains commas within quotes that need to be ignored, then the solution gets more complex and you'll likely want to use a dedicated comma-delimited file reading library. You've nothing to lose by showing a little initiative though and writing some code to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Java CSV](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv.php) and it's pretty easy.  See the [code examples](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php) as well.  However (summarizing what @Hovercraft Full Of Eels said), if your data are not overly complicated, [Java's String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) should work fine.

After parsing your data you can, you know, read the values and determine what to do from there.  Your description of what you need to do is practically an outline of a method with an `if ... else if ... else` structure, so start from that.